# Deriving incremental feature representations for bit flips

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, matrix, numpy

Given a boolean 3D matrix and a set of actions specifying bit flips at certain positions, a set of resulting matrices can be obtained, one matrix for each action, as if executing each bit flip individually.

A statistic (*feature representation*) defined on a matrix which for each row, column and depth counts the number of active bits at the same depth within some hexagonal distance in the first two dimensions of that row and column.

What's the fastest way of getting such a statistic for each of the resulting matrices (*afterstates*), given the previously mentioned original matrix (*grid*) and actions (`cell`, `atype` and `depths`)?

For example, given `cell = (3,2)`, `atype=NEW`, `depths=[3,58]` the first afterstate of `grid` can be obtained by `astate1 = np.copy(grid); astate[3,2,3] = 1`. Actions are guaranteed to be bit flips. If the feature representation for `grid` is known, the feature representation for `astate1` can be derived and need not be found from scratch.

In the code below, the naive approach (`afterstate_freps_naive`) and an incremental approach (`afterstate_freps_incremental`) are given. The naive approach should be easiest to understand.

This is the *hot* *hot* *hot* path of my system and I want to make it faster, but I'm no speed demon. Any tips and comments on anything else, small or large, is also appreciated. Below the code is some background which is not required reading but may make things more concrete.

```
import functools
from enum import Enum
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np


class Action(Enum):
    END = 0  # Actions of this type switches a bit in 'grid' from 1 to 0
    # Actions of this type switches a bit in 'grid' from 0 to 1,
    # provided that no nearby cells
    # (nearby as defined by the function 'neighbors(dist=2, *cell)')
    # already have this bit 'on' at the given depth
    NEW = 1


n_rows = 7
n_cols = 7
n_depths = 70


def hex_distance(cell_a, cell_b):
    r1, c1 = cell_a
    r2, c2 = cell_b
    return (abs(r1 - r2) + abs(r1 + c1 - r2 - c2) + abs(c1 - c2)) / 2


@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def neighbors(dist, row, col, separate, include_self, rows=7, cols=7):
    """
    Returns a list with indices of neighbors with a distance of 'dist' or less
    from the cell at (row, col)

    If 'include_self' is True, include the given (row, col)

    If 'separate' is True,
    return ([r1, r2, ...], [c1, c2, ...]) else
    return [(r1, c1), (r2, c2), ...]
    """
    if separate:
        rs = []
        cs = []
    else:
        idxs = []
    for r2 in range(rows):
        for c2 in range(cols):
            if (include_self or (row, col) != (r2, c2)) \
               and hex_distance((row, col), (r2, c2)) <= dist:
                if separate:
                    rs.append(r2)
                    cs.append(c2)
                else:
                    idxs.append((r2, c2))
    if separate:
        return (rs, cs)
    return idxs


def get_eligible_depths_bitmap(grid, cell):
    """Find eligible chs by bitwise ORing the allocation maps of neighbors"""
    neighs = neighbors(2, *cell, separate=True, include_self=True)
    alloc_map = np.bitwise_or.reduce(grid[neighs])
    return alloc_map


def get_eligible_depths(grid, cell):
    """
    Find the depths that are free (i.e. 0) in 'cell' and all of
    its neighbors within a distance of 2 or less.
    These are the eligible depths, i.e. those that can be assigned
    (taken in use) without violating the reuse constraint.
    """
    alloc_map = get_eligible_depths_bitmap(grid, cell)
    eligible = np.nonzero(np.logical_not(alloc_map))[0]
    return eligible


def get_n_eligible_depths(grid, cell):
    """Return the number of eligible depths"""
    alloc_map = get_eligible_depths_bitmap(grid, cell)
    n_eligible = np.count_nonzero(np.invert(alloc_map))
    return n_eligible


def afterstates(grid, cell, atype, depths):
    """Make an afterstate (resulting grid) for executing an action of type
    'atype' at position 'cell' on 'grid' for each depth listed 'depths'"""
    if atype == Action.END:
        targ_val = 0
    else:
        targ_val = 1
    grids = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(np.copy(grid), axis=0), len(depths), axis=0)
    for i, depth in enumerate(depths):
        # assert grids[i][cell][depth] != targ_val
        grids[i][cell][depth] = targ_val
    # assert grids.shape == (len(depths), rows, cols, depth)
    return grids


def feature_reps(grids):
    """
    Takes a grid or an array of grids and return the feature representations.

    For each cell, the number of eligible depths in that cell.
    For each cell-depth pair, the number of times that depth is
    occupied by neighbors (or self) with a distance of 4 or less.
    """
    # assert type(grids) == np.ndarray
    if grids.ndim == 3:
        grids = np.expand_dims(grids, axis=0)
    fgrids = np.zeros((len(grids), n_rows, n_cols, n_depths + 1), dtype=np.int16)
    for r in range(n_rows):
        for c in range(n_cols):
            neighs = neighbors(4, r, c, separate=True, include_self=True)
            n_used = np.count_nonzero(grids[:, neighs[0], neighs[1]], axis=1)
            fgrids[:, r, c, :-1] = n_used
            for i in range(len(grids)):
                n_eligible_depths = get_n_eligible_depths(grids[i], (r, c))
                fgrids[i, r, c, -1] = n_eligible_depths
    return fgrids


def afterstate_freps_naive(grid, cell, atype, depths):
    """
    Get the feature representation for each afterstate resulting from
    executing action of type 'atype' at 'depths'
    """
    astates = afterstates(grid, cell, atype, depths)
    freps = feature_reps(astates)
    return freps


def afterstate_freps_incremental(grid, cell, atype, depths):
    """
    Get the feature representation (as described in 'feature_reps')
    of the current grid, and from it derive the f.rep for each possible afterstate.
    """
    fgrid = feature_reps(grid)[0]
    r, c = cell
    neighs4 = neighbors(dist=4, row=r, col=c, separate=True, include_self=True)
    neighs2 = neighbors(dist=2, row=r, col=c, separate=False, include_self=True)
    fgrids = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(fgrid, axis=0), len(depths), axis=0)
    if atype == Action.END:
        # One less depth will be in use by the cell
        n_used_neighs_diff = -1
        # One more depth MIGHT become eligible.
        # Temporarily modify grid and check if that's the case
        n_elig_self_diff = 1
        grid[cell][depths] = 0
    else:
        # One more depth will be occupied
        n_used_neighs_diff = 1
        # One less depth will be eligible
        n_elig_self_diff = -1
    eligible_depths = [get_eligible_depths(grid, neigh2) for neigh2 in neighs2]
    for i, depth in enumerate(depths):
        fgrids[i, neighs4[0], neighs4[1], depth] += n_used_neighs_diff
        for j, neigh2 in enumerate(neighs2):
            if depth in eligible_depths[j]:
                fgrids[i, neigh2[0], neigh2[1], -1] += n_elig_self_diff
    if atype == Action.END:
        grid[cell][depths] = 1
    return fgrids


grid = np.zeros((7, 7, 70), dtype=np.bool)
where = ([
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6
], [
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5,
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5,
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
    5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6,
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
    5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6
], [
    18, 25, 38, 39, 54, 55, 61, 63, 65, 68, 5, 8, 16, 19, 20, 31, 35, 48, 51, 52, 56, 62,
    4, 7, 21, 23, 30, 32, 36, 37, 53, 58, 69, 1, 6, 14, 15, 24, 29, 34, 46, 47, 50, 57,
    60, 66, 67, 68, 3, 11, 22, 25, 26, 27, 35, 38, 42, 44, 49, 54, 59, 62, 64, 0, 10, 40,
    41, 55, 63, 16, 24, 31, 48, 50, 53, 56, 0, 1, 10, 14, 29, 33, 34, 46, 67, 9, 11, 12,
    22, 26, 42, 43, 44, 49, 17, 18, 39, 40, 41, 55, 65, 5, 19, 28, 48, 52, 56, 7, 13, 20,
    21, 32, 36, 37, 58, 61, 1, 6, 8, 14, 23, 29, 45, 47, 60, 67, 2, 3, 12, 26, 30, 33, 42,
    44, 59, 62, 69, 6, 15, 24, 27, 28, 50, 57, 66, 3, 13, 25, 38, 54, 59, 61, 0, 8, 10,
    16, 45, 51, 4, 9, 12, 30, 31, 43, 53, 69, 18, 34, 46, 68, 11, 15, 19, 22, 27, 35, 38,
    49, 64, 4, 7, 10, 17, 40, 51, 55, 63, 19, 48, 52, 53, 56, 58, 62, 1, 7, 14, 21, 23,
    29, 32, 34, 35, 46, 67, 6, 22, 27, 42, 44, 47, 49, 57, 63, 64, 66, 3, 17, 26, 39, 40,
    54, 0, 5, 24, 25, 41, 50, 56, 9, 28, 31, 48, 53, 58, 61, 65, 1, 6, 8, 14, 23, 32, 37,
    43, 46, 60, 66, 68, 9, 12, 37, 39, 40, 43, 2, 15, 18, 50, 68, 19, 28, 38, 48, 59, 61,
    1, 8, 10, 16, 21, 23, 32, 51, 52, 60, 12, 29, 30, 33, 44, 57, 69, 2, 3, 20, 26, 34,
    42, 47, 62, 0, 22, 25, 38, 45, 49, 64, 3, 8, 10, 13, 16, 26, 0, 25, 30, 31, 33, 41,
    45, 53, 56, 58, 9, 11, 34, 35, 43, 46, 65, 6, 13, 14, 15, 22, 37, 49, 55, 64, 66, 67,
    68, 19, 27, 39, 40, 54, 10, 11, 16, 17, 21, 36, 51, 52, 63, 4, 5, 24, 28, 31, 33, 41,
    48, 53, 57, 58, 1, 4, 5, 7, 14, 21, 22, 23, 49, 52, 20, 27, 39, 40, 57, 62, 2, 3, 17,
    18, 24, 36, 42, 50, 63, 4, 25, 31, 38, 41, 58, 59, 1, 8, 9, 23, 35, 43, 46, 60, 61,
    65, 12, 13, 14, 32, 37, 44, 50, 66, 68, 2, 3, 7, 18, 19, 20, 26, 27, 30, 34, 39, 42,
    47, 54, 62, 69
])
grid[where] = 1
cell_end = (0, 1)
cell_new = (3, 1)
depths_for_end_action = np.nonzero(grid[cell_end])[0]
depths_for_new_action = get_eligible_depths(grid, cell_new)


def f1():
    e1 = afterstate_freps_naive(grid, cell_end, Action.END, depths_for_end_action)
    n1 = afterstate_freps_naive(grid, cell_new, Action.NEW, depths_for_new_action)
    return e1, n1


def f2():
    e2 = afterstate_freps_incremental(grid, cell_end, Action.END, depths_for_end_action)
    n2 = afterstate_freps_incremental(grid, cell_new, Action.NEW, depths_for_new_action)
    return e2, n2

f2()  # Prime the memoization
print(timeit(f1, number=1000))
print(timeit(f2, number=1000))
# OK:
# r1, r2 = f1(), f2()
# assert (r1[0] == r2[0]).all()
# assert (r1[1] == r2[1]).all()
```

naive: 10.82

incremental: 4.74

There are some asserts in the code which all hold and might help you read it. The given benchmark parameters and grid are all typical of my simulation.

## Background:

Imagine a geographical area divided into disjoint regions (cells), where each cell has a base station which provides service for cellphones within its area. Two mobile callers within some distance of each other cannot use the same radio channel, lest their handsets will interfere. When a new caller requests service, we must therefore find the set of channels that are free in the cell of the caller and the neighboring cells within some given distance.

We can represent such an area and the channels in use with a boolean 3D matrix where the first two dimensions represent the geographical position (i.e. the cell) and the depth represents the channel. Cell areas often are circular in the real world, and we can approximate them as hexagons instead. Finding the neighbors of a cell we must therefore use the hexagonal distance.

Assigning new calls requires to find the channels that are free in the nearby area (*eligible channels*). However to select channels that will optimize grid usage as a whole, statistics, i.e. the feature representation, are useful. So when an action happens, i.e. a caller terminates a call or a new one requests service, there's a set of legal actions to take depending on the action type (`NEW` or `END`) and the grid. The afterstate is how the grid would look after performing an action, and the feature representation of that afterstate, when compared with the others, informs the decision making.